# How to disable Xperia Z2 burst mode?

Tags: photos, sony-xperia-z2

Almost every time I take a picture by camera hardkey, burst mode is activated automatically although I released the key immediately. I don't expect such a short press to activate burst mode. Therefore, a new folder for the burst series is created. Most of those folders have only 1 photo and those photos even have the same name. All of that make photo managing and syncing really frustrated.

How can I disable that feature? I don't want to disable burst mode completely.

Comment: Is using another Camera app not an option?

Comment: @Firelord other camera apps may start slower or can't be set as the default app to start with camera hard key

Comment: Well, you can disable the default camera app, and use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to bind your new camera app to hard key, though I get it that you're not inclined to have this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Camera settings(three dots) and turn on  the "Burst with longpress" option. This will let you shoot b ursts of photos simply by holding down the shutter key by long pressing. This way you can diable multiple burst photos at single click.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes but this will disable burst completely. Maybe I want a longer press for burst, otherwise a single shot is enough

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc No it won't disable burst mode completely. If you long press then  it switches to burst mode and otherwise a single click leaves you with single shot.

Comment: No, it never switches to burst mode. I've tried that before

Comment: Which button are you using to capture photos? The physical hardware button or the softkey capture button?

Comment: As I said, I'm using the hardkey. But regardless of the soft or hard key, the burst mode never turns on if I select Burst with longpress to OFF.